# Unable to authenticate to WordPress hosted in Azure in Linux with WordPressPCL and wp-api-jwt-auth

Tags: c#, wordpress, azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service

I am able to access the site programatically using WordPressPCL, and the library also manages to get a JWT token from the site, but when I try to call an authenticated API endpoint I just get 403 Forbidden.

Site running on Azure app service, linux container, using [this](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-quickstart-docker-images/tree/master/wordpress-alpine-php/0.72) docker image.

Comment: For all those flagging to close the question, it would be appropriate to at least leave a comment why...

Answer (score 1):

The solution it so simple it hurts.

Turns out that the Location of `define('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'your-top-secrect-key');` in `wp-config.php` (which is needed by the [JWT Authentication for the WP REST API](https://github.com/Tmeister/wp-api-jwt-auth) **cannot** be at the end of the file.

Moved it to where all other WP secrets are defined and things started working.